# Specified program for new process is a directory in Emacs with Pymacs

Tags: emacs, pymacs

I have tried to follow the Pymacs installation instructions as good as I could. It seems that my installation went fine, however, when I try M-x pymacs-eval with repr(2L**111) or M-x pymacs-load with os RET RET, I always end up getting a message saying 'Specified program for new process is a directory'. However, I can do M-x load-library RET pymacs RET and it I don't get an error. I am using Emacs 24.1.1 on Windows 7, along with Python 2.7.

Any help would be appreciated.